# Loading JSP on AJAX call in LIferay

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, liferay, portlet

I have a jsp page which is loaded on the click of a link, and a AJAX call is made which updates my model attritube, the problem I am facing is when I try to load my JSP thorugh AJAX, JSON data is printed on the page instead, I want to display JSP with updated values.Can somebody help ?

JS Code :

```
       $.ajax({
       url : resourceUrlStoredInVariable,
       dataType : "json",
       type: 'POST',
       contentType: 'application/json',
       data : {
          UserId : $(SELECTOR.UserID).val()
              },
          success : function(data) {

          $("#Container").load(resourceUrlStoredInVariable);
             }
           }).fail(function() {
            alert("Error..");

           });
```

Server Code:
@ResourceMapping("resourceHandlerId")

```
@ResponseBody
public void getStudentInfo(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response, Model model)
        throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException, PortletException {
    StudentInfo studentInfo= (StudentInfo) model.asMap().get(
            "studentInfo");
    facade.populateStudentInfo(studentInfo);

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.writeValue(response.getPortletOutputStream(), studentInfo);
}
```

Comment: resourceUrlStoredInVariable contains link to the jsp

Comment: For urI 'resourceUrlStoredInVariable',please create a resourceURL and use the serve resource method to update the data.You will be provided with certain values(updated) as per response from serveresource call or you can retrieve a whole file for download

Comment: I have created the resource URL, and also the data is updated, but when i  do  $("#Container").load(resourceUrlStoredInVariable) as i want to refresh the jsp, its just displays the model data instead of JSP with updated values.

Comment: Provide server side code. Also, your client side code doesnt seems good. load function itself makes ajax call. But you are first making ajax call by $.ajax and not using what it returns, and you are loading url on success of previous ajax call...flow doesnt seems correct.

Comment: Added the server code

Comment: Well. Server side code clearly indicates that you are explicitly setting response type as json and writing student object to response which gives json back to client.To return jsp code, you have to do something like this `String jspPath = ParamUtil.getString(resourceRequest, "jspPath");
        PortletSession portletSession = resourceRequest.getPortletSession();
        PortletContext portletContext = portletSession.getPortletContext();
        PortletRequestDispatcher dispatcher = portletContext.getRequestDispatcher(jspPath);
        dispatcher.include(resourceRequest,resourceResponse);`

Comment: Thanks I will try this and see if it works :)